# Why don't halogens form cations like H+?

Tags: ions, ionization-energy

The first ionization energy of hydrogen is $1312\;\mathrm{kJ\cdot mol}^{-1}$, which is larger than that of halogens such as chlorine, bromine, and iodine.

Given that observation, why don't halogens form $\ce{X+}$ ions like $\ce{H+}$?

Comment: It is a subtle matter. The halogens do exist in the +1 oxidation state, for example, in $\ce{OCl-}$. However, you aren't likely to see a naked $\ce{X+}$ cation. It is electron-deficient and would greatly prefer to form a bond to something else. *"Well, why does hydrogen form $\ce{H+}$ then?"* In fact, the naked $\ce{H+}$ ion does not exist either. In water, any naked $\ce{H+}$ ion will immediately form $\ce{H3O+}$. We only write $\ce{H+}$ as shorthand notation for "a Bronsted acid"; $\ce{H+}$ itself does not actually exist. Not in solution, at least.

Comment: @orthocresol What if we consider a case other than solution?

Comment: Even in superacidic media people have problems formulating true $\ce{H+}$. Superacids will *protonate* just about anything, showing how very unhappy the hydrogen would be to form a $\ce{H+}$ ion. $\ce{CH5+}$, anyone?

Comment: One context where $\ce{X+}$ form fairly readily is in ionizing plasma. But, *just about everything* forms cations in ionizing plasma, so ...

Comment: Iodine does form some compounds of $\ce{I+}$ in which it acts kinda like a metal.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40643/why-does-iodine-form-cations-sometimes .... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136529/what-is-the-correct-formula-for-iodonium-ion