# Are there terms for ions of chlorine other than chloride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, terminology, halogens

An ion of chlorine with a charge of −1 is called a chloride ion/anion.

Are there terms for other ions of chlorine, for example, $\ce{Cl+}$ or $\ce{Cl^2-}?$

Comment: *Chloride ion* is ok. Everyone will understand *chloride anion* but that phrase is redundant. Chloride already specifically means the ion $\ce{Cl-}$. // For $\ce{Cl+}$ is use *chlorine(I) cation* or *chlorine(1+) ion*. That is such an odd species that I'd explicitly specify the charge and not just say chlorine cation.

Comment: Questions regarding halogen forming cations: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40171/why-dont-halogens-form-cations-like-h ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40643/why-does-iodine-form-cations-sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "term" in your question refers to chemical nomenclature, the authoritative source of information would be the current edition of [IUPAC Red Book](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/redbook/) [1]. From [1, p. 70]:

> IR-5.3.2.2 *Monoatomic cations*
>
> The name of a monoatomic cation is that of the element with an appropriate charge number
> appended in parentheses.
>
> […]
>
> 5. $\ce{I+}$ iodine(1+)

Analogously, the name of $\ce{Cl+}$ is **chlorine(1+)**.

Further from [1, pp. 72–73]:

> IR-5.3.3.2 *Monoatomic anions*
>
> The name of a monoatomic anion is the element name (Table I) modiﬁed so as to carry the
> anion designator ‘ide’, either formed by replacing the ending of the element name (‘en’,
> ‘ese’, ‘ic’, ‘ine’, ‘ium’, ‘ogen’, ‘on’, ‘orus’, ‘um’, ‘ur’, ‘y’ or ‘ygen’) by ‘ide’ or by directly adding ‘ide’ as an ending to the element name.
>
> *Examples:*
>
> 1. chlorine, chloride
>
> […]
>
> Charge numbers and radical dots may be added as appropriate to specify anions fully.
>
> *Examples:*
> 14. $\ce{O^2-}$ oxide(2−), or oxide

So, the name for $\ce{Cl^2-}$ is **chloride(2−)**.

#### Reference

1. IUPAC. *Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry, IUPAC Recommendations 2005 (the “Red Book”)*, 1st ed.; Connelly, N. G., Damhus, T., Hartshorn, R. M., Hutton, A. T., Eds.; RSC Publishing: Cambridge, UK, **2005**. ISBN 978-0-85404-438-2.

Comment: @NilayGhosh I was wrong in that discussion, [Mithoron](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136529/what-is-the-correct-formula-for-iodonium-ion]#comment267675_136529) was correct. Chloronium is *not* $\ce{Cl+},$ it is $\ce{R2Cl+}$ (where $\ce{R}$ might as well be $\ce{H}).$ The [original paper](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac199567081307) explains it more clearly IMO—by the way, you could answer that question of yours by simply quoting the *onium compounds* section:)